# Proof of The GCD Distributive Indentity

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

$$\gcd(\text {lcm}(x, y), \text {lcm} (x, z)) = \text {lcm}(x,\gcd(y, z))$$
where $x,y,Z$ are three integers.

I came across this property on GCD but was not able to prove this.Can anyone suggest me a method.

Comment: Show that any prime power $p^k$ that divides the LHS also divides the RHS, and vice-versa.

Comment: Using only gcd laws yields a more general proof that works in any gcd domain, e.g. use the dual of the proof in my answer in the second link, which boils down to  $\ (a,b,c)(ab,bc,ac) = (a,b)(b,c)(a,c)\ \ $

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=p_1^{\alpha_1}p_2^{\alpha_2}...p_n^{\alpha_n}$,  $y=p_1^{\beta_1}p_2^{\beta_2}...p_n^{\beta_n}$ and $z=p_1^{\gamma_1}p_2^{\gamma_2}...p_n^{\gamma_n},$ where $\alpha_i,$ $\beta_i$ and $\gamma_i$ are non-negative integers and $p_i$ are different prime numbers.

Thus, we need to prove that:
$$\min\{\max\{\alpha_i,\beta_i\},\max\{\alpha_i,\gamma_i\}\}=\max\{\alpha_i,\min\{\beta_i,\gamma_i\}\}.$$
Can you end it now?

Comment: Perhaps min and max should change places in the last line?

Comment: @cgss Don't agree. $\gcd(4,6)=2=2^{\min\{2,1\}}3^{\min\{0,1\}}=2.$` I wait your reaction.

Comment: Yes you are right. I just did lcm = max, gcd = min and didn't pay attention to the fact that they were interchanged in the question itself.